# Content is not allowed in prolog error on google contact api in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios7, google-api-objc-client

I want to add iPhone contact in Google contact. I was used Google contact API.but it give me error Content is not allowed in prolog.
i searched this error but not succeeded.

i can authenticate Google through web view and get access-token. After that call API
my request is http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?access_token=ya29.1.AADtN_V0YDqLjA7-GmIRZN6Z_yNdfe3z-AmZMx0-ZPPyAvJFsThMaT1E5aF1Qg

please help me regarding this issue.

```
method type = post

Content type = application/atom+xml;charset=utf-8
```

Thanks

Comment: which parser are you using either xml or json

Comment: i am using json parser in ios

Comment: application/atom+json;charset=utf-8 try this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are json

```
application/atom+json;charset=utf-8
```

if your xml means try this

```
$headers = array('Content-Type: application/atom+xml; charset=utf-8',
'Content-Length: '. strlen($xml),
'Authorization: GoogleLogin '. trim($authToken)),
'Connection: close');
```

[For more information:](http://www.breathteching.com/2011/02/01/content-is-not-allowed-in-prolog-google-api/)

or

check your xml document tag

```
<!-- Correct -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```